# Rig Posing Error (Mesh deforms)

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I made a model, and rigged it, but when I tried to pose it, this happend. Any idea of what could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. 
I don't know what you did, what you wanted and what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks Frederik

Comment: what I mean is: Give us _much_ more information. Did you just enter pose mode and this happened? Do you have any constraints?...

Comment: "This happens" is like saying: My screen is black, fix it.

Comment: I don´t know why this happens, As I said, I made a model and rigged it and when I tried to pose it the mesh deformed in this weird way. I´m asking in case this is a common mistake that could be fixed by editing the mesh in edit mode

Comment: If you knew why it happened, you wouldn't ask the question. But on those screenshots all I see are crossed legs. I'm not even sure which is which. Do you have a mirror modifier, how does your entire rig look like, what's the weight painting? I am trying to help, but from what you provided, I can't.

Comment: Most likely no, it's a weight paint issue, but I'm still unsure about the details of "weird". I think the lack of conversation here is due to you providing no useful information.